# JSON of all private messages in Discord

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

How do I get all private messages with certain user in Discord? (through API using **curl**)

Answer (score 2):

Half possible.

If your account is a BOT account you can't. Bots can only see up to the 10 latest private channels and this will be removed for bots in the next gateway update [v7]. [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/hammerandchisel/discord-api-docs/issues/184).

However, if you are connecting with a user account, just send a GET request to `https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/channels` with the appropriate token and you should get a JSON array with all open channels.

So, to answer your question:

```
curl --header "Authorization: yourToken" https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/channels
```

Comment: old post but is this also not rate limited to 100 posts? as per: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits

meaning you could only ever get 100 messages at a time via their API or am i missing something here?